# columns values from two different sheet copy pasted in to another sheet and then comparing side by side cell and coloring them with green if matching

Tags: excel, vba

```
sub copycolmns() **code for copying columns data along with header in another sheet name paste sheet**

Sheets("copysheet1").Columns(11).Copy Destination:=Sheets("paste").Columns(1)
Sheets("copysheet2").Range("A1:A20").Copy
Sheets("paste").Range("B1").PasteSpecial xlPastevalues

End Sub

Sub reconncilirecords() ** this function to reconcile records and color them green if matching**

Dim col1 As Range, col2 as Range,Prod1 as String, Prod2 as String

Set col1 = Sheets("paste").Columns("A")
Set col2  = Sheets("Paste").Columns("B")

lr = Sheets("paste").Columns("A:B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
For r = 2 to lr
  Prod1 = Cells(r, col1.Column).Value
  Prod2 = Cells(r, col2.Column).Value

 If Prod1 = Prod2 Then
 Cells(r, col1.Column).Interior.Color = vbGreen
 Cells(r, col2.Column).Interior.Color = vbGreen
 Else
 Cells(r, col1.Column).Interior.Color = vbRed
 Cells(r, col2.Column).Interior.Color = vbRed
End If
Next r 
End Sub

Sub Result() **function to display if marching or not matching with message box**

Dim wj as Wrokbook
Dim ws_data as worksheet
Dim rng_data as Range

    Set wj = Activeworkbook
Set ws_data = ws.Sheets("paste")

Dim last_row as Long
last_row  = ws_data.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlup).Row

Set rng_data = Range("A2:A" & last_row)
If rng_data.Interior.Color = RGB(0,255,0) then
Msgbox" details verfd and matching"
Else
Msbxo "Mismatch found"
End If

End Sub
```

is there any way to speed up this process as whenever i run reconcile data 2nd sub function macro is getting hanged. Is there any other way to dynamically copy from sheet1 and sheet2 and recocnile the data and apply message box to check for last row.

Comment: Copy ranges as values, paste into your destination sheet; apply conditional formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Building on my comment; this is a mock-up, so untested... should give an idea:

```
destWS.Columns(1).value = sourceWS1.columns(2).value
destWS.Columns(2).value = sourceWS2.columns(2).value
With destWS.Range("A1:B" & destLastRow)
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$A1=$B1"
    With .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count)
       .SetFirstPriority
       With .Interior
           .Color = vbRed
       End With
    End With
End With
```

You will most likely want to use exact ranges, not columns, as it slows things down... a lot.

Comment: Above code is coloring all matching cells and blank cells from the entire sheet in to red which is not giving a clear picture . instead dynamically it has to color after finding last row, is there any other suggestion

Comment: @jagadeeshbudati it has to do with the ranges; it needs to be an exact range, though my untested example gives a range of two columns (`Range("A:B")`).  Changing to something like `Range("A1:B" & lastRow)` should resolve that issue.  Post updated.

Comment: I have used that code i see few challenges in this way, first one it is coloring green for matching cells and i want red for unmatched  cells . another thing which i did is i have coded macro to copy two more columns from each source sheet and when it conditional formatting is applied over this it color entire row with blank color even for the cells which are matching.below is the code

Comment: @ouroboros1 can you please help here.Using code given above i tried coding by adding two more extra columns for copying frmo two differenty source sheet and pasting it in one destination sheet. after pasting data from two sheets it is coloring only one color for matched cells leaving unmatched with default color. and another thins is when it' leaving default color for unmatched cells it is keeping enitre row in default color which means even for matched cells like c1=d1 it is changing color when it should be green becasue A1<>B1. is there anyway to try this